# screen resolution in c++

Tags: c++, user-interface, sdl, resolution

I made a simple game in C++ using SDL 1.2, and I used functions from wtypes.h to get display resolution, and then set game resolution at it's value. The problem is that when i compile it, exe file (my game's resolution) is dependent on resolution of computer it's compiled on. So when i copy exe file to another computer and it's run, the game resolution will be the same as my computer's resolution, not that computer's (unless they have same resolution). Is there a way get display resolution at runtime? I understand I can simply compile my cpp file at that computer, but that requires C:B/VS, dll files and linking dll files :/

Comment: Try getting the [current display mode](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode) before setting the game resolution.

Comment: How did you get the display resolution? I bet you're *already* getting it at runtime, unless you hard-coded it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SDL_GetVideoInfo` function returns a read-only pointer to a structure containing information about the video hardware. If it is called before `SDL_SetVideoMode`, member `current_w` and `current_h` of the returned structure will contain the pixel format of the best video mode.

```
#include "SDL.h"

SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
const SDL_VideoInfo* videoInfo = SDL_GetVideoInfo(); 
width = videoInfo->current_w;
height = videoInfo->current_h;
```